# Не получается как на макете. Нужно сделать прозрачным лого, а сами цифры оставить 100%

Tags: html, css

На макете логотип имеет прозрачность -0.43. Ставлю opacity, шрифт также становится бледным.

```css
body, h1, h2, h3, h4, p, a {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 100%; 
  font-weight: normal;
}

body {
 font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}
a{
 text-decoration: none;
}
.numbers {
  background:  rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.4)  ;
  z-index: 2;    
  height: 601px;  
  text-align: center; 
 }
.numbers h3 {
font-family: "Roboto Regular" sans-serif;
font-size: 36px;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #fff;
}
.about {
font-weight: bold;
}

.num { 
margin-top: 70px;
height: 450px;
background:  url(backlogo.png) no-repeat;

background-size: contain;
background-position: center;
z-index: 1; 
opacity: 0.5; 
color: #fff;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
font-family: "Roboto Regular" sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase; 
}

.num p   {
margin-left: 8rem;
font-size: 24px;
opacity: 1;

}

.num span {
font-size: 72px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css" />
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="http://allfont.ru/allfont.css?fonts=arial-narrow-bold" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <title>Свила</title>
</head>
<body>
 
 <main>
  <div class="numbers">
   <h3><span class="about">о нас</span> в цифрах</h3>
   <div class="num">
   
   <div class="n1"><p><span>2907</span> <br>проведенных <br> мероприятий</p></div>
   <div class="n2"><p><span>11</span><br>лет на рынке</p></div>
   <div class="n3"><p><span>7000</span><br>человек<br>крупнейшее мероприятие</p></div>
  </div>
  </div>

  

 </main>

 
</body>
</html>
```

[image: макет]

Comment: Ну, это логично - если родительский элемент (а num в данном случае родитель по отношению к блокам с текстом) прозрачен, то все дочерние элементы будут прозрачными. Нужно задавать прозрачность самой картинке, а не блоку.

Comment: получается ее как отдельный элемент через img, а не через background. Только так?

Comment: Можно через background псевдоэлемента сделать - спозиционировать его абсолютно внутри .num и уже ему задать фон и прозрачность.

Comment: Хотя проще действительно картинку вставить внутрь num, спозиционировать её абсолютно и задавать ей прозрачность.

Comment: А что мешает сделать лого в фш полупрозрачным, добавить как бекграунд, а цвет бекграунда через rgba с прозрачностью?

Answer (score 1):

Один из возможных вариантов решения Вашей проблемы: задаём фон не родительскому блоку, а псевдоэлементу (предварительно спозиционировав его абсолютно и растянув во весь размер .num):

```css
.numbers {
  background:  rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.4)  ;
  z-index: 2;    
  height: 601px;  
  text-align: center; 
 }
.numbers h3 {
font-family: "Roboto Regular" sans-serif;
font-size: 36px;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #fff;
}
.about {
font-weight: bold;
}

.num { 
margin-top: 70px;
height: 450px;
z-index: 1;
color: #fff;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
font-family: "Roboto Regular" sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase; 
position: relative;
}
.num > div {
  position: relative;
}
.num:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(https://www.sokolniki.com/content/images/0017386_0.jpeg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.num p   {
margin-left: 8rem;
font-size: 24px;
}

.num span {
font-size: 72px;
}
```

```html
<div class="numbers">
   <h3><span class="about">о нас</span> в цифрах</h3>
   <div class="num">
        <div class="n1"><p><span>2907</span> <br>проведенных <br> мероприятий</p></div>
        <div class="n2"><p><span>11</span><br>лет на рынке</p></div>
        <div class="n3"><p><span>7000</span><br>человек<br>крупнейшее мероприятие</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Заменил шрифт так как не могу найти шрифт из примера

> смотреть на весь экран

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.items {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  height: 60vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.items>h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

.blocks {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.blocks p {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.blocks-item {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.section img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/swtjJy2/section.png" alt="">
  <div class="items">
    <h2>О нас в цифрах</h2>
    <div class="blocks">
      <div class="blocks-item">
        <h2>2907</h2>
        <p>Проведённых <br>мероприятий</p>
      </div>
      <div class="blocks-item">
        <h2>11</h2>
        <p>Лет на рынке</p>
      </div>
      <div class="blocks-item">
        <h2>7000</h2>
        <p>Человек <br>крупнейшее мероприятие</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```